# ASP.NET chatting design and speed issues

Tags: asp.net

Ok. I am making a random chatting website here, and the website needs to know each user's new visit datetime and a randomID in order to retrieve the messages he/she made in a chatting room. When a user comes in to my website, he/she gets a unique random ID and start to talk to another person. Every comments they make gets saved in a database along with a randomly assigned chatroomID. Then, the database loads the messages in the chatroom (every 1 second) by identifying the users' new visit dates to the chatroomID and retrieving all the users' messages associated with the chatroomID in chronological order (from the new visit date). Do you think that this is a well-designed way to create a random chatting website and if not is there a better design alternative? :D If I reload the messages from the database every 1 second, won't there be speed or traffic issues? If I am not clear on my explanation, plz leave msg and ask me for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open source project was just released called [JabbR](https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR) based on [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

Comment: I am a newbie on this field. Can you explain me more clearly why your suggestion is relevant to my question?:D

Comment: Because what you are trying to build is already done and done well in an open source project by people who work for Microsoft. I can't think of a better example than that.

Comment: Thanks, rick! I will check it out and see if I can get any help from it:)